# Correct way to calculate the content-length of an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, curl

Is the below the correct way to calculate the `content-length` of an associative array to `POST` in PHP CURL?

```
$contentLength = strlen(json_encode($myAssocArray)); // is this correct??

...

$headers = array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  "Content-length: $contentLength"
);
```

I am getting HTTP `100` responses back which makes me think that my content-length is wrong. **Note, I know CURL can auto calulate the content length header but if I don't include this header for the server I am sending this to they send back a HTTP `411` (Length Required) response.**

Comment: What value are you sending to cURL, `json_encode($myAssocArray)`? Does the value contain multibyte characters? If you set the content-length to an invalid value (`1`) do you receive the same response? Usually a `100` response code means that everything is "Okay" and you can continue with the request or ignore the response if the request is complete. What does the API you're interfacing with specify for the requirements for the request? EG: send headers, then send body, etc.

Comment: Why don't you do count() on the array?